# $Z(G/ Z(G)) = 1$ Prove or disprove.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. The claim is that if $H = Z(G)$ (the center of $G$), then $Z(G/H) = 1$. I either have to prove or disprove the claim. My intuition says its false and I was thinking of using $G = Q_8$ (the quaternion group) as the counter example. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Well, it should be fairly simple to test $Q_8$; you know its center. What is the order of the quotient by the center, and what do you know about groups of that order?

Comment: Well the center is quite simply $\pm$ 1. The order of the quotient by the center should be 2 no?

Comment: @JordanReed $Q_8$ has eight elements, its centre has two elements, so $|G/H|=$ what here?

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that $Z(Q_8)\cong\Bbb Z_2$, and that the quotient $Q_8/Z(Q_8)\cong\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2$, the Klein four group.  Since the latter group is abelian, it has nontrivial center.